# Records on the web page is not updated, while the records in the database are updated successfully

Tags: java, mysql, caching, spring-boot, phpmyadmin

I am developing a web application with Springboot + Thymeleaf + MySql + JdbcTemplate.

Despite database records are updated successfully with phpMyadmin, the records displayed on my application don't get updated.(I am confirming the records with phpMyadmin & my applicaton through browser.) 
Ctrl+F5 does not solve the issue.

100% reproducable by follwoing steps below.

- 1)Start my application and search record A1.
- 2)Change the record(A1)-value with phpMyadmin manually.
- 3)Search A1 with my app again.
- 4)The change made at #2 does not reflect on my page.
- 5)Re-start my application and search A1
- 6)The change made at #2 reflect on my page.

What should I do to reflect the changes to my application without restarting it?
 Could you tell me how to solve the issue?

Here is my application.yml

```
spring:
    multipart:
         max-file-size: 328MB
         max-request-size: 328MB
    datasource:
        url:  jdbc:mysql://localhost/ichego?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
        username: 
        password: 
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        tomcat:
          default-auto-commit: false
          cache:
    type: none
        server:   port: 8080
    thymeleaf:
        cache: none
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String search25(Model model,
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParameters, 
        @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> multiMap,
        Locale locale) {

    List<lot> obj = _objDao.queryWithId("123");
    model.addAttribute("data23", obj.get(0).name);

    return "test";
}
```

DAO

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

public List<lot> queryWithId(String id)
{
    List<lot> obj = null;
    StringBuilder sbSql = new StringBuilder();
    sbSql.append("  select           ");
    sbSql.append("       *           ");
    sbSql.append("  from             ");
    sbSql.append("       lot         ");
    sbSql.append("  where            ");
    sbSql.append("       id=?        ");

    try{
        obj = jdbc.query(sbSql.toString(),new Object[] {id}, new lotMapper());

    }catch(DataAccessException exda){
        logger.error("Err55:" + exda.toString());
        return null;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Err56:" + ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
    finally{

    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: For instance: Start up my application and do search,  and update database records with phpMyadmin, the updated data does not reflect on the web page

Comment: how do you load the data?

Comment: I am using (@Anwired) JdbcTemplate.

Comment: Can you post the respective code on your controller?